# Swagger always showing code 0 with No Content message

Tags: json, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, http-status-codes

I have this @RestController method in my SpringBoot Application:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "fetch")
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<? extends Object> fetch(@RequestBody UserDTO user){

        return new ResponseEntity("Depricated you should use v1.0.1...", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);

    }
```

Every time I call the endpoint I get a code 0 with a no content message on swagger. But using the Restlet chrome extension I see my message and the NOT_ACCEPTABLE 406 code. Any idea why this is happening only with swagger? And how to fix it?

Comment: Is [CORS](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/cors.md) enabled on your API server? Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: yes CORS is enabled but I have no errors in my console

Comment: What is your `spring` version?

Comment: `...
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>...`